# Vue Router production issues

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a project on Vue.js, and there is some issue with production mode and vue router. On development version I have no issues, but if I compile it and run on production mode, and go to some link - it show me 404 error code

Here is my route js file:

```
Vue.use(VueRouter)

const routes = [
{
  path: '/',
  name: 'Home',
  component: Home
},
{
  path: '*',
  name: 'Agents',
  component: Agents
},
{
  path: '/agents',
  name: 'Agents',
  component: Agents
},
{
  path: '/compare-agents',
  name: 'Compare',
  component: Compare
},
{
  path: '/input',
  name: 'InputFields',
  component: InputFields
},
{
  path: '/check-pay',
  name: 'CheckPay',
  component: CheckPay
},
{
  path: '/success',
  name: 'Success',
  component: Success
},
]

const router = new VueRouter({
  mode: 'history',
 base: process.env.BASE_URL,
  routes
})

export default router
```

For example, I wanna go to Agents page, by link like http::/localhost:8080/agents and it's works (dev verison), but if I compile, it's getting 404 error

Website is localted in core directory.
I can visit homepage, use nginx server, and here it's conf file:

```
worker_processes 4;

events { worker_connections 1024; }

http {
    server {
        listen 80;
        root  /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index  index.html
        include /etc/nginx/mime.types;

        location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What value are you supplying for `base`? Does it differ between dev und prod?

Comment: Thanks, but I've got an answer, it was a problem with nginx file and some cors configures, devops dev have just fixed that